# Issue displaying variables in Batch

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, echo

I am trying to display a list of variables in Batch, however I don't get the variables back. I get the command back but stripped of % and spaces.

```
echo 1 %11A1% %11B1% %11C1% %11D1% %11E1% %11F1% %11G1% %11H1% %11I1% %11J1%
```

turns into

```
1 1A111B111C111D111E111F111G111H111I111J1
```

I have done variables in other batches and displayed them similarly without problem. Any help is appreciated!

Current code here: http://hastebin.com/sutasipiju.dos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a problem with the naming of your variables. As they start with a number, the fisrt character in name of variable preceded by a percent sign is being considered as a parameter. So, `%11A1%` (and in the rest of variables) are getting translated to `%1 1A1 ...`

From command line this works without problems as there are no parameter substitution, but in batch files variables starting with a number generate this kind of problems.

There are two solutions to this.

- Rename all the variables to something that not start with a number
- Enable delayed expansion ('setlocal enabledelayedexpansion') and
  change the sintax from `%11A1%` to `!11A1!`

First option is probably better as is simpler and can generate less problems, but both can make it work

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with your variablenames, which should not start with a numeric.

When batch sees `echo %11A1%...`

it substitutes the first command-line parameter for the `%1`, hence, assuming you have provided no parameters, this will become

```
[nothing]1A1...
```

Solution : start your variables with some other character. "A..Z" are traditional. If you want to be a little exotic, then `$` and `#` seem obvious choices.